# Request for member in something not a structure or union?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code:

```
people[nextfreeplace] -> personName = name;
people[nextfreeplace] -> age = age;

typedef struct person
{
  char *personName;
  int age;
}Person;
```

The person declaration is `Person *people[]`

I am receiving an `error: request for member 'personName' in something not a structure or union`

```
error: request for member 'age' in something not a structure or union
```

But i am not sure what is wrong with the program.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a *minimal* , complete, compilable example? what you've said doesn't add up. This compiles fine: http://ideone.com/GgWtaB

Answer (score 2):

I assume `people` is a `Person *` or `Person[]`.

When using operator `->`, you dereference and access the variable. It is equivalent of doing `(*var).personName`.

Change the `->` with a dot, as when using person[1], you already dereference your pointer, and then access your variable like you would do with a simple `Person var`

```
people[nextfreeplace].personName = name;
people[nextfreeplace].age = age;
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am still getting the same error. You are right people is `Person *people[]`

Comment: Is your code using char *personName as a pointer ot as a characcter array. Seeing the structure declaration, it is a pointer to a string. Have you used it in this manner throughout your code.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the people declaration ? Using `Person *people[]` should normally work using `people[1]->personName;` And are you sure the error comes from the lines you pasted in ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` instead of `->` since you are using an array of structures.

Comment: Now knowing this declaration `Person *people[]`, your answer is not correct (anymore).

Comment: Why the upvote? This simply isn't the right answer, to not say it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of a type needs to be done prior to accessing the (members of an) instance of a type.

```
typedef struct person
{
  char *personName;
  int age;
}Person;

...

Person *people[];

...

people[nextfreeplace] -> personName = name;
people[nextfreeplace] -> age = age;
```